Getting full article of a new
"I'm working on a project for my school where I'm building a news application. I want to fetch the full content of a news article. How can I achieve this using Android Studio?"
If the news API I used only provides a brief summary instead of the full text, and I need the complete content, how can I achieve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
